# Simple vba sub giving error Compile error: Expected: =

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple sub in excel vba:

```
Private Sub AlignText(r As Integer, c As Integer)                                                 'A sub to align the data in the cell
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(r, c).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Cells(r, c).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

I just want to supply column and row numbers to align text. I have tried putting in the full path to the cells using full sheet references too, but that doesn't help.

When I try to use the sub:

```
AlignText(NextRow, 16)
```

for example, I get the error:

```
'Compile error: Expected: ='
```

I have written very very similar subs before, that aligned text as well as doing other things, and they have worked fine. This must be something simple, but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis - `AlignText NextRow, 16`

Comment: Thanks, so simple! I don't see why it doesn't need the parentheses, but I'm glad that it works!

Comment: Parenthesis are typically for Functions, not Subs. It was thinking that you were expecting it to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
AlignText NextRow, 16
```

**Note**: You should try to avoid using `ActiveSheet`. I would add the `Worksheet` object to your `Sub` as well.

```
Private Sub AlignText(Sht As Worksheet, r As Integer, c As Integer)

'A sub to align the data in the cell
With Sht
    .Cells(r, c).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Cells(r, c).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

End Sub
```

And call it by using:

```
AlignText ActiveSheet, NextRow, 16 ' <-- if you have to use ActiveSheet
```

Comment: `Call` is deprecated and should be avoided.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I know, as you can see in the code in my answer, right ?

Comment: I mean remove it from your 'Or Call AlignText...'. You do show how to use it, but you also offer up using `Call` initially.

Comment: Thanks @Shai Rado